# Do the Cages in Electric Cage Matches spawn in specific patterns?

Tags: twisted-metal

I've only played a couple of *Twisted Metal's* levels on Story mode, including the NYC Electric Cage Match.

I found the match more than a bit frustrating, as I sometimes burned quite a bit of my grace period just trying to find the next Cage.

Do the cages always spawn in the same spots, in the same order, so once I learn the pattern I will be able to minimize how much grace time I will burn up by planning my routes?  Or are they random?

Answer (score 1):

There are certain cage spawn points, so look for them when you play to judge where the next one will spawn.
You need decent speed, armour, and some good weapons on your vehicle.

I had a lot of problems with this myself, I usually have Kamikaze or Reaper for their speed.  If I have some grace left to switch out, I keep Sweet Tooth and Death Warrant on back up.